# Error in clips.BuildRule

Tags: python, aptana, python-2.6, clips

I am using pyClips (which is Clips embedded in python) for building a knowledge
base.  I want to add a new rule to a knowledge base file by calling a function
that implements the rule shown in this function:

```
def normalRule(clips, i, path):
    rule_name = 'rule_' + str(i)
    rule_prec = '(phase ?phase)'
    rule_prec += '?address1 <-(Organ (name ?organ))'
    rule_prec += '?address2 <-(Surgical-Action (action ?action))'
    rule_prec += '?address3 <-(Medical-Devices (tool-name ?tool))'
    rule_body = '(if(=(str-compare ?*pickupEvent* "no")0) then'
    rule_body += '(bind ?predicted-action ?action)'
    rule_body += '(bind ?*current-action* ?predicted-action)'
    rule_body += '(bind ?ex-tool ?tool)'
    rule_body += 'else'
    rule_body += '(bind ?actual-action ?action)'
    rule_body += '(bind ?s-tool ?tool)'
    rule_body += '(retract ?address1 ?address2 ?address3)'
    rule_body += '(if (and (=(str-compare ?predicted-action ?actual-action)0)\
    (=(str-compare ?ex-tool ?s-tool) 0)) then'
    rule_body += '(updateAction ?*current-action* ?actual-action)'
    rule_body += 'else'
    rule_body += '( if (not(=(str-compare ?predicted-action ?actual-action)0)) then'
    rule_body += '(updateAction ?*current-action* ?actual-action)'
    rule_body += '(assert (You have mistake: incorrect action))'
    rule_body += '(bind ?*number-of-mistakes* (+ ?*number-of-mistakes* 1)))'
    rule_body += '(if (not(=(str-compare ?ex-tool ?s-tool) 0)) then'
    rule_body += '(updateAction ?*current-action* ?actual-action)'
    rule_body += '(assert (You have mistake: incorrect surgical device))'
    rule_body += '(bind ?*number-of-mistakes* (+ ?*number-of-mistakes* 1))'
    rule_body += ')))'

    rule = clips.BuildRule(rule_name, rule_prec, rule_body)
```

The rule inside this function works fine when i apply it using Clips, but now I want to
build a new rule every time the function is being called.

But when I called this function, I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\DELL\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\
    Interface\src\ruleModel\ruleTypes.py", line 305,
    in <module> normalRule(clips, 1, "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\bjareb\tt.py")          
File "C:\Users\DELL\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\
    Interface\src\ruleModel\ruleTypes.py", line 39,
    in normalRule rule = clips.BuildRule(rule_name, rule_prec, rule_body)
File "C:\Python26\lib\clips\_clips_wrap.py", line 149, in _WRAPPER return f(*args)
File "C:\Python26\lib\clips\_clips_wrap.py", line 238, in _WRAPPER return f(*newargs)
File "C:\Python26\lib\clips\_clips_wrap.py", line 3317, in BuildRule _c.build(construct)
    _clips.ClipsError: C08: syntax error, or unable to parse expression
```

So please, I revised it many times and there is nothing wrong in the rule
construction, also it works when I use Clips, so how do I solve this?

Comment: Those `assert` lines look funny -- are error strings for the user really unquoted?  You might also wish to re-write the entire thing using [Python's `"""` here-document-strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Python), to get rid of all the extra `'` and `rule_body +=` fragments.

Comment: am workin with pyclips, the sigle qout here doen't mean comments!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to be careful with whitespaces that you are missing in your program. Eoln's are needed as well as spaces for your comparison statements. So, your program should look like this:

```
rule_prec = '(phase ?phase)\n'
rule_prec += '?address1 <-(Organ (name ?organ))\n'
rule_prec += '?address2 <-(Surgical-Action (action ?action))\n'
rule_prec += '?address3 <-(Medical-Devices (tool-name ?tool))\n'
rule_body = '(if(=(str-compare ?*pickupEvent* "no") 0) then\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?predicted-action ?action)\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?*current-action* ?predicted-action)\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?ex-tool ?tool)\n'
rule_body += 'else\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?actual-action ?action)\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?s-tool ?tool)\n'
rule_body += '(retract ?address1 ?address2 ?address3)\n'
rule_body += '(if (and (= (str-compare ?predicted-action ?actual-action) 0) \
(=(str-compare ?ex-tool ?s-tool) 0)) then\n'
rule_body += '(updateAction ?*current-action* ?actual-action)\n'
rule_body += 'else\n'
rule_body += '( if (not (= (str-compare ?predicted-action ?actual-action) 0)) then\n'
rule_body += '(updateAction ?*current-action* ?actual-action)\n'
rule_body += '(assert (You have mistake: incorrect action))\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?*number-of-mistakes* (+ ?*number-of-mistakes* 1)))\n'
rule_body += '(if (not (= (str-compare ?ex-tool ?s-tool) 0)) then\n'
rule_body += '(updateAction ?*current-action* ?actual-action)\n'
rule_body += '(assert (You have mistake: incorrect surgical device))\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?*number-of-mistakes* (+ ?*number-of-mistakes* 1))\n'
rule_body += ')))\n'
```

Second, if you are using PyClips and feel comfortable with CLIPS, use the following lines in order to get the real CLIPS error message for your rule. I tried solving your problem but there are several problems in your rule's pattern and action parts.

```
import logging.config
engine = clips.Environment()
try:
rule_name = 'rule_1'
rule_prec = '(phase ?phase)\n'
rule_prec += '?address1 <-(Organ (name ?organ))\n'
rule_prec += '?address2 <-(Surgical-Action (action ?action))\n'
rule_prec += '?address3 <-(Medical-Devices (tool-name ?tool))\n'
rule_body = '(if(=(str-compare ?*pickupEvent* "no") 0) then\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?predicted-action ?action)\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?*current-action* ?predicted-action)\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?ex-tool ?tool)\n'
rule_body += 'else\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?actual-action ?action)\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?s-tool ?tool)\n'
rule_body += '(retract ?address1 ?address2 ?address3)\n'
rule_body += '(if (and (= (str-compare ?predicted-action ?actual-action) 0) \
(=(str-compare ?ex-tool ?s-tool) 0)) then\n'
rule_body += '(updateAction ?*current-action* ?actual-action)\n'
rule_body += 'else\n'
rule_body += '( if (not (= (str-compare ?predicted-action ?actual-action) 0)) then\n'
rule_body += '(updateAction ?*current-action* ?actual-action)\n'
rule_body += '(assert (You have mistake: incorrect action))\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?*number-of-mistakes* (+ ?*number-of-mistakes* 1)))\n'
rule_body += '(if (not (= (str-compare ?ex-tool ?s-tool) 0)) then\n'
rule_body += '(updateAction ?*current-action* ?actual-action)\n'
rule_body += '(assert (You have mistake: incorrect surgical device))\n'
rule_body += '(bind ?*number-of-mistakes* (+ ?*number-of-mistakes* 1))\n'
rule_body += ')))\n'

rule=clips.BuildRule(rule_name, rule_prec, rule_body,"test rule")
    except clips.ClipsError:
logging.error(clips.ErrorStream.Read())
```